# reading data in single line with matching word

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

My file
    $ cat input.txt

```
localhost,acbd,shdkk,hjk:java,web,was
asd,jkll,dhjd,ksjss,sdd:was,java,web,http
hdgdhd,kxmnc,sshshs:noo,dhdd,sss
```

I want to develop script to get the below output when i run it on server

```
java
web
http
```

I want output below when i run it on server called "asd"

```
was
java
web
http
```

plesae help me on this

Comment: what have you tried so far?  given the sample data, what are you expecting to see as output?

Comment: c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I am trying to get using AWK

Comment: awk -F '[()]' '{print $1}' /$USER2/sqm/Processlist.dat

Comment: I want output like below when matching this word "acbd" output should be javaweb,was

Comment: @HarikumarReddy, comments are not meant to post samples or codes, so please do update your question with sample expected output.Also let us know are you asking user to enter details or in awk program itself you want to directly pass(hard coded) values? Please do all these details in your question and let  us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 updated the Question

Comment: @HarikumarReddy, one request Hari, please post your efforts(which you shown in comments) in your question, on stack overflow we encourage users to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though its not much clear, based on my assumptions; like you want to check value in first column(where delimiter is `:` for each line) if passed variable is present in it or not;if present then print 2nd column.

```
awk -v pass_value="asd" '
BEGIN{
  FS=":"
}
{
  delete array
  delete array1
  num=split($1,array,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    array1[array[i]]
  }
}
(pass_value in array1){
  gsub(/,/," ",$2)
  print $2
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: your assumption is correct but i want output to be printed without delimiter (,) after delimiter value should be in next line

Comment: Thanks a lot @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @HarikumarReddy, your welcome and in case you need any new question help post a new question and lemme know here, cheers bro